# How to pause an Activity till I get facebook id while signing in in Android?

Tags: android

While using facebook in Android to log in/register, it takes a while for facebook to send the request. Thus, how do I pause the activity(show a process dialog) till I get the facebook id/username of the user who is trying to register? I can't do this in the base Listener as it is a background process.

I tried out using AsyncTask but I'm either confused how to do it or it can't be done. Mostly the former. I did this:

```
  public class FacebookOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {  





        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {  
            super.onPreExecute();



                mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                reg = "facebook";
                SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, Register.this);
                SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
                //SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());

        } 
        @Override 
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

         }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        { 


               fillFormFb(); //Fills the form with the data from fb
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mLoginButton.init(Register.this, mFacebook,permissions);


            return null;
        }

          }
```

Comment: have you solved your issue???

Comment: No. It is crashing. Check the new edit. Thanks for the help till now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AsyncTask to run your process in background.. you can show your progressbar while loading the operation.

```
public class FacebookOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{  
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

} 
@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
 }

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

{ 
      //Post Execute
       dialog.cancel();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

  // Your operation..Dont Edit Any Views here

    return null;
}
```

}

**EDIT**

I think you can follow [this](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/) link to integrate facebook with your app. It will helpful for you.

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried your procedure but I am not sure how and where can I fit in the facebook sign in here.

Comment: Do the facebook signup in doInBackground(). This can do network I/O and wait for responses without messing up your UI thread.  When the facebook handshake is finished, doInBackground() exits and onPostExecute() runs in the UI thread, updating the display.